Extract URL from a hyperlink using REGEXEXTRACT not working in arrayformula
I have a sheet that gets a hyperlink added to it everytime a form is submitted. I want to convert that hyperlink into a URL.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MjPKOF-qLRUxwlcVNcdiPtDym0YbkHWkgb4vAfDIrcU/edit?usp=sharing
I found a formula that will do this for a row, but when I try to use it in an array formula, it returns the same value for all rows instead of the next value. What am I doing wrong.
={"EDIT FORM URL"; 
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AG2:AG="",,REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(AG2:AG999), "(https?://[^""]+)")))}



FORMULATEXT will not behave as an array function even inside an array function.
Your regular expression can be simplified to "http[^""]+"

Use MAP or BYROW as follows:
={"EDIT FORM URL";
  IFNA(MAP(AG2:AG, LAMBDA(x,
    REGEXEXTRACT(
      FORMULATEXT(x), "http[^""]+"))))} 

FORMULATEXT  IFNA  LAMBDA  MAP  REGEXEXTRACT
